# MySQL PHP: Blog Post Archive Drop Down Menu

Tags: php, mysql, archive

I am new to MySQL as well as PHP and just had a few questions.

Currently I am trying to create an archive menu for my posts that are looked up in my MySQL DB named "posts".

It should look like,

```
2010 (2)
   September (2)
     Bellavisa
     Mists of Netting

   July (1)
     Turkey is cool!

2009 (1)
   May (1)
     Cock of the Rock
```

but I am currently getting,

```
2010 (2)
   September (2)
     Bellavisa


   July (1)
     Turkey is cool!

2009 (1)
   May (1)
     Cock of the Rock
```

Hence, I am missing the second post title under September

Any help would be appreciated! My code is below!

```
$sql = "SELECT Month(time) as Month, Year(time) as Year,
title, COUNT(*) AS total FROM posts GROUP BY Year, Month ORDER BY time DESC";
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);

$currentMonth = 0;

$currentYear = 0;

if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){
  $title = $row["title"];
     // if the year changes you have to display another year
    if($row['Year'] != $currentYear) {

        // reinitialize current month
        $currentMonth = 0;

        // display the current year
        #echo "<li class=\"cl-year\">{$row['Year']} ({$row['total']})</li>";
echo "          <ul>";
echo "          <li onClick = 'show(\"{$row['Year']}\")' > <img src='images/triangle_closed.gif' id=img_{$row['Year']}>{$row['Year']} ({$row['total']})</li>\n"; 
echo "          <li>\n"; 
echo "          <ul id = {$row['Year']} style='display:none;'>\n"; 
#echo "</ul>";



        // change the current year
        $currentYear = $row['Year'];
    }

    // if the month changes you have to display another month
    if($row['Month'] != $currentMonth) {

        // display the current month
        $monthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $row['Month'], 10));
#echo "<ul>";
echo "              <li onClick = 'show(\"{$row['Year']}$monthName\")' > <img src='images/triangle_closed.gif' id=img_{$row['Year']}$monthName>$monthName ({$row['total']})</li>\n"; 
echo "              <li>\n"; 
echo "                <ul id = {$row['Year']}$monthName style='display:none;'>\n"; 
echo "                  <li class='cl-posts active'><a href='\base\item.php?id=$title'>".$title."</a></li>\n"; 
echo "                </ul>\n"; 
echo "              </li>\n"; 
        #echo "<li class=\"cl-month\">$monthName ({$row['total']})</li>";

        // change the current month
        $currentMonth = $row['Month'];
    }

    // display posts within the current month
    #echo "<li class='cl-posts active'><a href='\base\item.php?id=$title'>".$title."</a></li>";
}
}

 $conn->close();
 ?>
```

Thank You!

Comment: what is your problem ?

Comment: I guess you simply miss to close your HTML list. Indent the produced HTML with an editor and you'll see.

Comment: although it does list two posts under September, it is only printing the first post. Why will it not print the second? It obviously sees another post

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I have fixed the indentation problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your query, you're grouping by Year, so it's normal not to show the second title and also you're trying to count the number of years. I would suggest mixing a subQuery so you can have both results, so change

```
SELECT Month(time) as Month, Year(time) as Year, title, COUNT(*) AS total FROM posts GROUP BY Year, Month ORDER BY time DESC
```

to

```
SELECT Month, Year, p.title, t.total
FROM posts p 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Year(time) Year, Month(time) Month, SUM(1) FROM posts GROUP BY Year, Month) t ON t.Year = Year(p.time) AND t.Month = Month(p.time)
ORDER BY time DESC
```

Also, for the identation problem, you are opening new  before closing the last, each time a Year or Month changes.

Validate for $currentYear and $currentMonth, if they are non-zero, you must close the  before opening a new one.

Comment: im getting a "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\base\main3.php on line 164" error which is in "if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {" ? what does this mean..

Comment: It means $stmt failed, can you check $conn error status, to see if there is something wrong in query, i cant see any wrong...

Comment: the only thing I changed in my code was the sql statement as mentioned above, so is there something wrong with that? If I change it back to the old one it seems to work fine.

Comment: also p.title, and t.total show up differently than normal, they are a purple color in sublime rather than a red/yellow color like operations and variables..

Comment: Can you give a little dump of your posts table (gist for example), so i can test. For the colors, i suggest to check the generated html.

Comment: title "bellavisa" content "yadadada" time "timestamp ..." Author "author"

Comment: Which connection type are you using?? PDO?

Comment: MYSQL queries using mysqli

Comment: I ended up having to fix my select statement! Thank you.